# Detect sms: browser support on Browser

Tags: php, javascript, sms, browser-detection

I have a problem with a mobile page and sms: links. The page is mainly visited by android and iOS based smartphones via QR-scanning apps.

Especially on the iPhone there are a few QR-Apps with integrated Browsers (instances of webkit?), which don't support sms: Links (bad. and don't know why). Default Browsers do support sms: links without any problems.

I'd like to disable the sms: links, if there isn't support.

If anyone has an idea how to detect it (via javascript or php) that would be nice!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can detect it, but maybe you can try to read the User Agent of the QRCode integrated browser? (should be a WebView, and there is hope than WebView doesn't have a proper User Agent).

Here is the code to disable auto-linking anyway:

```
<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
```

Comment: Thx for your input! I've found a way with the User Agent,... :)

Comment: PS:
`if ( !navigator.userAgent.match( "Safari/" ) )` (used, if it is an iPhone/iPad; "a bit" dirty, but it works...)

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way is to use [DeviceAtlas](http://deviceatlas.com/) or [WURFL](http://wurfl.sourceforge.net/).  They both have databases of mobile phone properties.  You can use server-side detection (PHP) or they have APIs for use with JavaScript.

In WURFL, the property "xhtml_send_sms_string" will tell you if you can use sms: or smsto: or if it isn't supported.

In DeviceAtlas, the property "uriSchemeSms" or "uriSchemeSmsTo" will tell you the same thing.